# Create postgres user during boot

Tags: linux, postgresql, monit

I'm running a bash file from monit during boot, that bash file starts my postgres server.

if my database directory is not present, I do:

1- initdb (postgresql/data/)
   su - edge -c '/usr/bin/initdb -D ${DBDIR}'

2- copy modified pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf files to (postgresql/data/)

3- start my server
   su - edge -c " /usr/bin/pg_ctl -w -D ${DBDIR} -l logfile start"

4- postgres createuser 
   - su - $User -c '${DBDIR} -e -s postgres'

after the execution of the bash file 
postgresql/data/ is created
files are copied
server is started, 
but user is not created so I cannot access my database

error :  /usr/bin/psql -U postgres
         psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't decipher your step #4, but the reason why the `postgres` role does not exist is because the step #1 is run by a user `edge` **and** it doesn't ask for the creation of a `postgres` role through `-U`, so it creates an `egde` role as superuser instead.

Per `initdb` documentation:

> -U username
>   --username=username
>
> Selects the user name of the database superuser. This **defaults to the name of the effective user running initdb**. It is really not
>   important what the superuser's name is, but one might choose to keep
>   the customary name postgres, even if the operating system user's name
>   is different.

Either do `initdb -U postgres`, or if you prefer a superuser named `edge`, keep it like this but start `psql` with `psql -U edge`, or set the `PGUSER` environment variable to `edge` to avoid typing that each time.

Comment: Thanks, 

I had read that part of the docs, but for whatever reason, I read that the -U was used to give the name of the created superuser, not create it. 

should have caught it just by the fact that the superuser couldn't be created before initdb.